# Combination of ts files and mp4 in m3u playlist

Tags: mp4, playlist, m3u8, m3u

I need to create one m3u or m3u8 playlist which will contain combination of ts files and mp4

I tryed to make it like this :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-VERSION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10,
http://someurl.mp4/segment1_0_av.ts?null=
#EXTINF:10,
http://someurl2.mp4/segment2_0_av.ts?null=
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
#EXTINF:6,
http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4
```

But this doesnt work so i tryed to make two playlists one of ts files and second one of mp4 file like this and call them from one m3u playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=2,BANDWIDTH=2055000,RESOLUTION=1280x720
playlist.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2055000,RESOLUTION=1280x720
playlist2.m3u8
```

This also doesnt work and play only one playlist.

Is it even possible and if how ? Thanks

Comment: What program are you using to try and play these files?

Comment: VLC player but only for testing , result should be played in Smart TV

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it? Is it possible to have MP4s in m3u8 playlist?